# Copy Data from one workbbok to another by transposing data based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA automation to be completed as part of my work. I have to copy data from workbook1 to workbook2 (different workbooks), but the challenge is data needs to be transposed based on criteria, simple transpose is not working as need to check some conditions.Region1,Region2.....will vary so need to paste dynamically.

I am attaching file with structure.

Any help will save me a lot, Thanks in advance for help.

Workbook1:
[image]

Workbook2:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I have tried transposing the data, but there are merged cells, so unable to convert it to vertical view, under each merged cell there is one more hierarchy to capture but unable to do it.

Comment: How have you tied transposing it? Please show your code. We need to see it in order to fix it or tell you where you went wrong. I mean you just need to do a simple transpose of the range and then merge the regions that are the same that's it.